# Dialing an extension automatically

Tags: contacts, calls

How do I add a phone number extension to a contact in a way that it will dial the extension automatically a few seconds after a call is connected? I have seen 4 different ways that appear to work on different devices.  "p", "w", ";" and ",". Is there one official way that works across devices and Android versions?

Answer (score 2):

In the dialer in Stock ICS and jellyBean it only uses the following:

- Pause: ',' - pauses then sends the remaining digits
- Wait:  ';' - waits for you to confirm sending of the remaining digits.